# Wix embedded mysql does not start due CommandFailedException due 'Stream closed'

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu

Trying to run my embedded mysql based Unit tests I get an exception with this part:

`Failed to instantiate [com.wix.mysql.EmbeddedMysql]: Factory method 'getEmbeddedMysql' threw exception; nested exception is com.wix.mysql.exceptions.CommandFailedException: Command 'CREATE USER 'sa'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '';' on schema 'information_schema' failed with message 'Stream closed'`

The same unit test and environment setup work on my MacBook

This machine with the error is an Ubuntu 20.04
Wix version is 4.6.2; Java 8, mysql.connector 8.0.24

I tried changing the dependencies versions and also tried with Java 11.
Run from within IntelliJ and on the command line. Same result.

Comment: I was able to solve this by  installing *libncurses5* (`apt install libncurses5`)  as explained in this comment: https://github.com/wix/wix-embedded-mysql/issues/116#issuecomment-444927280

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me put the full comment I found in Github which helped me to fix this and I'm pretty sure most of the people seeing this in Ubuntu will find this as the solution:

> I had this same issue with MySQL 5.7, while working on another open source project. I cloned the wix-embedded-mysql repository and ran the tests using the master branch, which also failed in the exact same way, except that I received a longer, more thorough message in the catch.

> The issue was that I was on Ubuntu and did not have the ncurses 5 shared library installed. On ubuntu, I installed libncurses5 (apt install libncurses5) and everything started working (all tests on wix, and on my project).

> I hope this helps resolve the issue.

Thanks to https://github.com/codesplode